# Нужны ли кавычки в названии?

Tags: пунктуация, названия

Нужны ли кавычки в названии произведения внутри произведения?
У меня есть повесть о поэте по имени Василий. Поэт в ходе сюжета выпускает сборник стихов, которые называет "Правда Василия". 
Я как автор хочу назвать повесть в честь этого сборника - "Правда Василия". Нужно ли брать его в кавычки по праву названия внутри названия? 
Работает ли здесь принцип цитирования? 
Или кавычки могут быть уместны лишь в том случае, если повесть я назову: Сборник стихов "Правда Василия"?

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется в виду именно сборник, то кавычки нужны.

Однако стоит подумать о целесообразности такого названия. Так ли уж важен этот сборник, а может, здесь имеется в виду то, что для автора важно именно его название? Тогда без кавычек - пусть в центре будет это сочетание.

А можно подумать о более интересном названии, например, "Правда о "Правде Василия" (кавычки поставить разной конфигурации) или "Где ж она, правда Василия?"

Честно говоря, я бы не остановилась на таком названии, поискала бы другое.